# Best practice to sum and format numbers to dollar values with 2 decimal points?

Tags: php

Here's the code I came up with, I want to:

1. sum price + shipping to a total
2. always display formatted numbers with two decimal points
3. have a dollar sign at the start for all three values
4. display an alternative "free shipping" if the shipping value is zero.

PHP:

```
$price0 = "356";
$ship0 = "9.9";
$tprice0 = $price0 + $ship0;

$price1 = number_format((float)$price0, 2, '.', '');
$ship1 = number_format((float)$ship0, 2, '.', '');
$tprice1 = number_format((float)$tprice0, 2, '.', '');

if($ship0 == 0) { $shipping1 = '<span class="free">Free Shipping</span>'; } else { $shipping1 = "$$ship1"; }
```

HTML:

```
Price: $<?php echo $price1; ?> 
Shipping: <?php echo $shipping1; ?>
Total: $<?php echo $tprice?>
```

Is this the best practice? (e.g, I'm using a double dollar sign), and is there a way to make the code cleaner / shorter?

**EDIT:**
note that I want to have this practice for several products in the same page, so is there a way to make it shorter?

```
$price0b = "223";
$ship0b = "5.5";
$tprice0b = $price0b + $ship0b;

$price1b = number_format((float)$price0b, 2, '.', '');
$ship1b = number_format((float)$ship0b, 2, '.', '');
$tprice1b = number_format((float)$tprice0b, 2, '.', '');

if($ship0b == 0) { $shipping1b = '<span class="free">Free Shipping</span>'; } else { $shipping1b = "$$ship1b"; }
```

EDIT2:

I'm getting a class not found error with this code:

```
<?php

$price = "356";
$shipping = "0";
$total_price = $price0 + $ship0;

$oNumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL, '¤ #,##0.00');
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Price: <?= $oNumberFormatter->format( (float) $price ); ?>
Shipping: <?= !$ship0b ? "<span class=\"free\">Free Shipping</span>" : $oNumberFormatter->format( (float) $shipping ); ?>
Total: <?= $oNumberFormatter->format( (float) $total_price ); ?>
```

Comment: You're being very _creative_ with your variable names. Try coming up with better names for your variables. `$ship0` seems to determine when an order has free shipping but why is it sometimes a string `"9.9"` and sometimes an int `0`? `$tprice0` and `$tprice1` could very well be `$total_price` and `$total_price_formatted`. This is much clearer.

Comment: The `NumberFormatter` object is more helpful as it allows you to specify the format by locale : http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php or even ICU Decimal format; e.g. `¤ #,##0.00`

Comment: I would move the `number_format()` calls into the HTML file because that's the only place where you need the values formatted.

Comment: `ship0` doesn't mean zero cost, the `0` means this is the pre-formatted number, while the `1` pairs are the post formatted numbers

Comment: edited my question with another thing to consider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format a number to en_US currency format you can create a NumberFormatter object like this:

```
$oNumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
```

In this instance prices will be formatted up to *normal* rules for the given locale; for instance **$9.95** for 'en_US` or **€ 9,95** for 'nl_NL'

---

If you want a specific [ICU Decimal format](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1DecimalFormat.html) you could use:

```
$oNumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL, '¤ #,##0.00');
```

The currency symbol (**¤**) in the format will automatically be converted, when echoed out, to the correct symbol specified by the locale string; so for 'en_US' the dollar symbol (**$**) will be used - for 'nl_NL' the Euro (**€**) and so on.

---

Either way, in your product display loop, to display the correctly formatted product price, you need only (assuming your product price here is `$price`) use:

```
<?= $oNumberFormatter->format( (float) $price); ?>
```

... and for your free shipping insert:

```
<?= !$shipping ? "<span class=\"free\">Free Shipping</span>" : $oNumberFormatter->format( (float) $shipping ); ?>
```

Full details on the `NumberFormatter` class are at: http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

---

**Just an edit to answer the question in the comments**

> Ok, thanks. can you explain what you did with the shipping part? I
>   didn't understand how that format is working. also, how to insert a
>   dollar sign if for the time being I will use Free Shipping" : number_format((float)$shipping,
>   2, '.', ''); ?> ?

`<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo`

I'm just using a ternary operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php (scroll down the page a little) - it's just a sort of shorthand for directly assigning a value based on a sort of if (**?**) else (**:**) notation:

`!$shipping` equates to `$shipping == false` which equates to `$shipping == 0` since PHP is loosely typed, so:

```
<?= !$shipping ? "<span class=\"free\">Free Shipping</span>" : $oNumberFormatter->format( (float) $shipping ); ?>
```

... is equivalent to ...

```
<?php
if($shipping == 0) {
  echo "<span class=\"free\">Free Shipping</span>";
}
else {
  echo $oNumberFormatter->format( (float) $shipping );
}
?>
```

---

And for literally outputting a `$` string... just use a non-interpolated string literal. PHP has 2 types of [string literal](http://php.net/language.types.string) (well, 4 with `heredoc` syntaxes) but essentially an interpolated string is enclosed in double quotes and will parse variables.

```
<?php
$sWord = "BADGERS";
echo "I like $sWord";
?>
```

Results in `I like BADGERS`

Whereas a non-interpolated string (enclosed in apostrophes) will treat `$` literally - it won't interpolate variables:

```
<?php
$sWord = "BADGERS";
echo 'I like $sWord';
?>
```

Results in `I like $sWord` literally.

So you can echo out your currency value, with a prefixed dollar sign, like so:

```
echo '$' . number_format( (float) $shipping, 2, '.', '');
```

---

Comment: thanks but I'm getting: `Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in .. line 14`

Comment: @rockyraw ah - what version of PHP are you using? It only got rolled into the standard distribution with 5.3 - otherwise it's part of the PECL Intl module

Comment: version 5.4.26, I don't think it has to do with the function but rather with the code.. maybe it's impossible to simply write `$oNumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);` in the code.

Comment: I posted the full code in my question, getting `Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in /home/saleturbo/public_html/template4.php on line 7`

Comment: @rockyraw - no, its quite possible, I built a Currency object around it... however PHP does need to have the Intl module running, if you're on a Windows dev box, check in php.ini for the line **extension=php_intl.dll** and make sure it's uncommented - it'll also appear in a `phpinfo()` script under the heading **Intl**

Comment: I'm on apache and this is kinda beyond my knowledge, I'm not really a PHP programmer, just gathering code bits :/ when I tried using `$oformat = new number_format(2, '.', '');` I got the exact same error so it doesn't have to do with the `NumberFormatter` function

Comment: Easiest way to check then is to create a PHP file called phpinfo.php (or whatever you like) and in that file simply have `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` - navigating to that file in your browser (http://127.0.0.1/phpinfo.php for instance) will display a full PHP report - do a search for **Intl** and if you don't see a section titled **intl** (Internationalization support) then your PHP install isn't running it and anything that relies on that will fail. So `Class NumberFormatter not found...`

Comment: Oh - and the reason you'd get that error with `$oformat = new number_format(2, '.', '');` is that `number_format` is a function, not a class.

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't see `intl` there. shouldn't that be a default feature? should I contact my webhost and have them install that?

Comment: It's worth giving it a shot - it's certainly a worthwhile feature (especially for me since I've got a site running in English, Dutch, French and German) but not all distros roll it into their default bundle for some reason.

Comment: Ok, thanks. can you explain what you did with the shipping part? I didn't understand how that format is working. also, how to insert a dollar sign if for the time being I will use `<?= !$shipping ? "<span class=\"free\">Free Shipping</span>" : number_format((float)$shipping, 2, '.', ''); ?>` ?

Comment: thanks! i get a syntax error though with the full line: `Shipping: <?= !$shipping ? "<span class=\"free\">Free Shipping</span>" : echo '$' . number_format( (float) $shipping, 2, '.', ''); ?>`

Comment: @rockyraw - heh, you don't need that echo in there before the '$' - just : `<?= !$shipping ? "<span class=\"free\">Free Shipping</span>" : '$' . number_format( (float) $shipping, 2, '.', ''); ?>` the `<?=` at the start has it covered.

Comment: *phew* did we get there in end? :D

Answer (score 0):

i will most likely do this

PHP

```
$price = "356";
$ship = "9.9";
$tprice = $price + $ship;
```

HTML

```
Price: $<?php echo setdecimalPoint($price); ?> 
<?php if($ship == 0) { ?>
<span class="free">Free Shipping</span>
<?php }else{ ?>
Shipping: <?php echo setdecimalPoint($shipping); ?>
<?php } ?>
Total: $<?php echo setdecimalPoint($tprice)?>
```

Comment: can you explain how does `formatdecimal` differs from what I'm using and why would it be better? where do I control the number of decimal digits here?

Comment: No much different, just tidy up your code into a function.